# How to list cells applied different calculation expression depending on another table's value

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match

First, I'm sorry for poor English.

I'd like to list cells with different calculation depending on other table's value. I'll explain more details with tables.

Source table:

| Type | Value | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | True |
| 1 | 10 | False |
| 0 | 10 | True |
| 0 | 10 | False |

Result table:

| Type | Calculated | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 * 2 | True |
| 1 | 10 + 1 | False |

1. I want to list only {'Type' = 1} cells, but types are several from 0 to 10.
2. if Source table's {'Condition' = True}, want to return {'Value' * 2}, else {'Value' + 1}

I think I can solve this with ARRAYFORMULA with QUERY or INDEX with MATCH but I'm not confident with.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(hstack(A:A,if(C:C,B:B*2,B:B+1),C:C),A:A=1)
```

[image]

Comment: really thank you, this is what I look for.